# "Generic PnP" Monitor, but Manufacturer Doesn't Publish a Driver (?) - how to fix?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, display

Installed a Asus VE247H monitor tonight. My Win 7 64-bit identifies it as a "Generic PnP Monitor".

How can I get Windows to identify my monitor? I looked at the Asus web site and for the VE247, there is no driver listed, which I'm assuming means the driver comes with Windows...?

I was quite surprised...expected to need to load a driver.

I went to device manager and tried Update Driver, Let me Pick.  If I uncheck "show compatible hardware," there are a lot of manufacturers listed, but not Asus.  Weird - they do sell quite a few monitors :-)

Do manufacturers release monitors expecting to use the Windows Generic PnP mode?

The monitor is driving the right display (1920x1080), I just find the output a little grainy and unsharp.  I'm running over DVI on a GeForce 650 Ti card, which is working fine and is current driver-wise.

Comment: In my experience, monitors don't usually need drivers. On the other hand, LCDs shouldn't look like anything that could be described as "grainy", assuming you're running them at their native resolution. I would check the controls on the monitor itself (actually, the first thing I'd do is hit the "auto adjust" button, if you haven't tried that already). This page may be helpful: http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/

Answer (score 1):

Unless they have additional, non-standard hardware, monitors do not have drivers.  If they did, it would be terribly inconvenient to swap them out.  Fortunately, graphics cards output in standard formats that all monitors recognize.  Sometimes you will find "drivers" for monitors on websites, however this is a misnomer.  These "drivers" are really just windows [.INF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) files, which gives Windows some information, but no actual binary driver.

I looked up that model and it is at least a 7 year old LCD monitor.  That coupled with the fact you are complaining it is not working as expected, I suspect it could be damaged.

Try connecting another monitor.  If the image is better, then more than likely, the Asus monitor is defective.